# Isn't my book using the summation notation incorrectly when writing $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(x)\Delta x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, notation

My book was introducing the concept of integrals and wrote this:

$$\text{Area under the curve of $f(x)$}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(x)\Delta x\tag{1}$$

My problem with $(1)$ is that there is no $n$ in the expression $f(x)\Delta x$. So, what does $n=1$ below the summation notation even mean then? To elucidate my point:

Let,

$y=f(x)$

Now,

$$\text{Area under the curve of $f(x)$ from $y_1$ to $y_N$}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^{N}y_n\Delta x\tag{2}$$

Now, the usage of $n$ makes sense because there is an actual $n$ present in the expression $y_n\Delta x$.

So, is my book wrong?

Comment: yeah, it's sloppy notation. it should read something like $f(x_n)\Delta x$

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman Thanks for your answer kind sir. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, the intention with the notation is clear but it is technically wrong. Even the subdivision size $\Delta x$ should at least depend on the number of subdivisions $N$ so should be $\Delta x_N$.

Comment: @0XLR So, you mean that $N$ depends on $\Delta x$?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic you can also think of it that way. Depends on whether you decide on the subdivision size first or the number of subdivisions first. Either way, there has to some sort of dependence between $\Delta x$ and $N$.

Comment: @0XLR "Even the subdivision size Δx should at least depend on the number of subdivisions N so should be $Δx_N$", did you mean to write $x_n$ and instead you wrote $x_N$ kind sir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed sloppy notation. The proper way of writing it is to say the following. Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is a given bounded function. Let $P=\{x_0,\dots, x_N\}$ be a partition of the interval $[a,b]$, meaning that $a=x_0<x_1<\cdots< x_N=b$. Suppose also that we're given a collection of points $\{\xi_1,\dots, \xi_N\}$, where $\xi_1\in[x_0,x_1], \cdots, \xi_N\in [x_{N-1},x_N]$. We call $(P,\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^N)$ a *tagged partition* of $[a,b]$.

Corresponding to this tagged partition, we consider the Riemann sum
\begin{align}
R(f,P,\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^N):=\sum_{i=1}^Nf(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})\equiv\sum_{i=1}^Nf(\xi_i)\Delta x_i
\end{align}
where we defined $\Delta x_i:=x_i-x_{i-1}$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots, N\}$. Here, $\xi_i$ is just an intermediate point of the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$. Also, let us define $\|P\|:=\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq N}\Delta x_i$; this is called the *mesh* of the partition $P$.

Finally, with all the notation above, we say that the function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if the following limit exists:
\begin{align}
\lim_{\|P\|\to 0}R(f,P,\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^N)
\end{align}
i.e we require the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{\|P\|\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^Nf(\xi_i)\Delta x_i\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
to exist. More explicitly, what this means is:

> There is a number $I\in\Bbb{R}$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any tagged partition $(P=\{x_i\}_{i=0}^N,\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^N)$ of $[a,b]$, if $\|P\|<\delta$ then
> \begin{align}
> \left|R(f,P,\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^N)-I\right|:=\left|\sum_{i=1}^Nf(\xi_i)\Delta x_i - I\right|<\epsilon.
> \end{align}

One can easily show that if the number $I$ exists, then it is unique.

In this case, we call the unique number $I$ the Riemann integral of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$, and write this as $\int_a^bf$. We define this to be the (signed) area bounded by the graph of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ and the horizontal axis.

---

So long story short, $(*)$ is what you should be writing. The choice of index $i$ is irrelevant. I can use $j$ or $\alpha$ or $n$ or any other letter I like, for example, $\sum_{\beta=1}^Nf(\xi_{\beta})\Delta x_{\beta}$. Writing $\sum_{n=1}^Nf(x)\Delta x$ is incorrect for two reasons. First, it makes it seem like $\Delta x$ is a fixed number and $x$ is fixed, so the sum should just evaluate to $Nf(x)\Delta x$; of course this isn't the intended meaning.

We have to allow several things to vary: the number of points in the partition (i.e $N$), and also the spacing (i.e we're not assuming all the $\Delta x_i$'s are equal), and also we have allow for arbitrary intermediate points (i.e arbitrary choice of $\xi_i$'s).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, sir! At first, it seemed impenetrable; now that I've read it a few times, I'm starting to understand it. I had a question though. If the subintervals are $Δx1, Δx2, Δx3, Δx4...ΔxN$, and if $Δx2$ is the greatest interval in size/magnitude, then $Δx2$ is the mesh or the norm of the partition: am I understanding you correctly sir?

Comment: Also, the main idea behind making the mesh of the partition approach zero is that if the mesh approaches zero, all the other subintervals approach zero as well (and N approaches infinity), right? Also, instead of writing $||P||\to 0$, we could've written $N\to\infty$ in $(*)$, right?

Comment: Yes for your first comment. For the second, your first half is right. But no we can't just say "let $N\to\infty$". Since we're not (and we shouldn't) making any assumptions about spacing of the points $x_i$, it is possible that $N\to \infty$ while the mesh is large. For example, in the interval $[0,1]$, say we consider $0,\frac{1}{2},1$. The mesh is now $1/2$. We can increase the number of points indefinitely by just adding more on the right half, but adding none on the left. Then the number of points increases indefinitely while the mesh remains $1/2$.

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah actually your book wants to write $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(x_n)\Delta x_n$$

$\Delta x_n$ is the width of the elemental rectangle and $f(x_)$ is the value of the function at the near neighbor of $x_$.

Comment: Kind sir, do you mean $\Delta x$ or $\Delta x_n$? I think it should be $\Delta x$.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic the $\Delta x_n$ need not be uniform in the definition of the riemann integral